# errors while installing adt

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

hello i have this error while installing adt :
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.
and i tried to change the site from https to http but although i had the following error:
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
after that i tried to uncheck the option “Contact all update sites during install to find required software” but i had the following error:
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=[R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 --> [R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720, action=).
Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720.
please help me fix that..

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:

Help > Install New Software...

Click Add...

- Name --> ADT Plugin
- Location --> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

You should see "Developer Tools" and "NDK Plugins" for options to install.

If this does not work you will need to give more details about what you are doing/ the nature of your error to explore other possible solutions.

Comment: i did that before and i had the following error:
 Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: after that as i said above i changed the site from https to http but i had this error:
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=)